# Vue.js cannot access method of component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two Vue.js components *Lobby* and *Game*. I want to use *Game* as a model that contains all logic to create a game and trigger it via the Lobby component.

if I run the app and click on the button I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: game.createGame is not a function
    at click (eval at createFunction (vue.js:9923), <anonymous>:2:76)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (vue.js:1827)
```

How can I access the game method from the *Lobby* component?  Thanks!

```
    let Game = {        
        methods: {
            createGame: function () {
                console.log('createGame clicked')
            }
        }
    }



    let Lobby = {
        template: `
            <div>
                    <button v-on:click="game.createGame()">Create</button>
            </div>
        `,
        data()  {
            return {
                'game': Game
            }
        },

    }
```

Comment: Put a method on Lobby that wraps the Game method and call it that way. But that looks like bad practice the way you are going with that code. Would make more sense if the template was in the game component and you use a slot on Lobby to nest the game component.

Comment: Can you put the whole code to get the hierarchical idea of the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a method from another component you can use `Event bus` from Vue.js 
The main idea is that you have to emit a global call in A component and receive it in B component using `bus.$on`

```
var bus = new Vue();

Vue.component('Increment', {
  template: "#inc",
  data: function() {
    return ({count: 0})
  },
  methods: {
    increment: function(){
      var increment = ++this.count
      bus.$emit('inc', increment)
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('Display', {
  template: "#display",
  data: function(){
    return {count: 0}
  },
  created: function(){
    bus.$on('inc', function(num){
       this.count = num    
  }.bind(this));
  }
})


vm = new Vue({
  el: "#example",
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emwcoy36/

Comment: thanks. its my first two hours with vue.js ... seems to be I need to play around more to understand the relationships.

Comment: If you're beginner I can highly recommend you this youtube course about `vue.js`: [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LYrN_cAJoA&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gQcYgjhBoeQH7wiAyZNrYa)